# why do we write Row row = sheet.getRow(0); Cell cell = row.getCell(0); lines while retrieving data from Excel in selenium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
1.Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
2.Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
3.System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0));
4.Row row1 = sheet.getRow(1);
5.Cell cell1 = row1.getCell(1);
6.System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1));
7.Row row2 = sheet.getRow(1);
8.Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(1);
9.System.out.println(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0));
```

why do we  write lines 1,2,4,5,7,8 as without those lines also lines 3,6,9 are retrieving the data

Answer (score 0):

I think in 1,2,4,5,7,8 you just storing the values for the cells and rows while accessing the the exact cell value you can use the 3,6,9 for retrieving the data but there are some operations where you want manipulations on the rows then you will be need the row or cell variables. Like, set some column value of shift rows you will be needing those:

```
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();  
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet");  
        Row row     = sheet.createRow(1);  
        Row row2    = sheet.createRow(2);  
        Cell cell   = row.createCell(1);  
        Cell cell2  = row2.createCell(1);  
        cell2.setCellValue("Hello, Javatpoint");              
        sheet.shiftRows(1, 2, -1);
```

Hope this answers you query.
Thanks